# OpenLayers controls keyboard shortcuts

Tags: openlayers-2, dojo

I'd like to hook up keyboard shortcuts to my map controls e.g. holding down 'z' will activate the zoombox tool etc. I can't seen anything relevent in the API for doing this. Is it easily done? My controls are sat beneath dojo toggle buttons and menu items like so:

```js
// zoom tool
zoomBoxTool = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox();
map.addControl(zoomBoxTool);

// zoom button
var zoomBoxButton = new dijit.form.ToggleButton({
    label : "Zoom",
    iconClass: "zoomIcon",
    showLabel : false,
    onChange : function(val) {
        toggleTool(val, zoomBoxTool, this)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

in my application, with using extjs and openlayers, in extjs app. i have control whether capslock open or not with some charcodes...

in openlayers you can add some handleKeyEvent script to openlayers/lib/Handler/Keyboard.js which is locate end of the code.

you can look at for [Javascript Char Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)
and some [Openlayers Code](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@openlayers.org/msg01805.html)

i hope it helps you