# Implementing non-default keyboard shortcuts in Openlayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

Following on from [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/openlayers-controls-keyboard-shortcuts), I am trying to implement @Aragon's suggestion and add some keyboard shortcuts to OpenLayers via a `handleKeyEvent` method in `OpenLayers.Handler.Keyboard`.  This ought to be a simple task that many people implement but for some reason I'm just not getting it.

```
var keyboardControl = new OpenLayers.Control();

var keyHandler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Keyboard(keyboardControl, {
    handleKeyEvent: function(evt) {
            alert("You pressed a key!");
            switch(evt.keyCode) {
                case 87:
                    doSomething([0, 1]);
                case 83:
                    doSomething([0,-1]);
                case 65:
                    doSomething([1,0]);
                case 68:
                    doSomething([-1,0])
            }
        },
});

function doSomething(vals){
    alert("Something will happen here eventually...");
};

map.addControl(keyboardControl);
```

I get no errors but neither of my alerts get fired.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to activate your new key handler :

```
keyHandler.activate();
```

You may also work a little on your callbacks.
You will find a working example based on your code at the following URL : http://www.empreinte-urbaine.eu/mapping/ol_keyboard.html

Comment: Doh! It's obvious when you mention it.  Many thanks for implementing a working example though (+1).  That has already been very helpful.

Comment: Don't worry, I've implemented something similar before and I was looking at your code going 'Theres nothing wrong wih that...'